# Making a window not resizable in Windows

Tags: python, winapi, windows-7, tkinter, pywin32

I've been working with Windows API calls so that I can get some native Windows window styles working with Tkinter. I've run into problems when I try to prevent the window from being resizable. Using `root.resizable(False, False)` before the window is mapped produces an effect not unlike that of the `root.overrideredirect(True)` method; calling it after the style has been changed causes all sorts of craziness (The window freaks out). I'm thinking that there's probably a windows specific equivalent to `root.resizable(False, False)`.  How would I get this working? Keep in mind I have a handle to the Tkinter window.

Code :

```
import Tkinter as tk
import string, win32ui, win32con

def decaption(event):
    root = event.widget

    # makes a handle to the window
    handle = string.atoi(root.wm_frame(), 0)

    # changes the style
    frame = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(handle)
    frame.ModifyStyle(win32con.WS_CAPTION, 0, win32con.SWP_FRAMECHANGED)

    root.bind("<Map>", None)

root = tk.Tk()

# changes the style when the window is mapped
root.bind("<Map>", decaption)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about the python angle, but another method to prevent a window from being resizable (in addition to changing its style) is to handle WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and override the new size with your desired size.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ideas:

- You can try removing the WS_THICKFRAME style:

  ```
  frame.ModifyStyle(win32con.WS_THICKFRAME, 0)
  ```
- Another alternative is to handle the [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message that returns the minimum and maximum width and height for a window. In your case, you would return the current width and height. You can get this information with [GetWindowRect](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32gui__GetWindowRect_meth.html).